# Yii2 custom validation rule, compare function using three attributes

Tags: validation, yii2, attributes, rules

I'm trying to modify a custom validation rule in Yii2. I want to compare three attributes, the scenario is like:

> *harga_total* must be greater than (*harga_satuan* times banyak_satuan)

This is what I'm doing:

```
public function rules() {
        return [            
            [['harga_total'], 'validateHarga', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false],
        ];
    }


public function validateHarga() {
        $a = $this->harga_total;
        $b = $this->harga_satuan;
        $c = $this->banyak_satuan;
        if ($a <= ($b * $c)) {
            $this->addError('harga_total', 'Harga Total harus lebih besar atau sama dengan harga satuan dikali dengan banyak satuan');
        }
    }
```

But the form doesn't show error or anything.

The other validation rules (not in a function like this one) I do in this model work fine.

I also tried doing it in rules function, like this:

```
['harga_total', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => ($this->harga_satuan * $this->banyak_satuan), 'operator' => '>=','message' => 'Harga total harus lebih atau sama dengan harga satuan', 'type' => 'number'],
```

Doesn't work either.

Comment: are you trying to get this validation work for frontend/client-side?

Comment: Yes. But didn't work.

Comment: you should create a standalone validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**:

Turns out the function works but not directly on client side.
It works after all other validation rules passed.